# Vuetify fixed table headers only work for last header row ( previous ones are hidden on scroll )

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

Given the a Vuetify table with fixed headers ( [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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) )

```
<script setup lang="ts">
  import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";

  const tableMatrix = ref(Array(100).fill([null, null]))
</script>

<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-table density="compact" fixed-header>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr v-for="(row, rowIndex) in tableMatrix" :key="rowIndex">
            <template v-for="(cell, columnIndex) in row" :key="columnIndex">
              <td>{{ rowIndex }}</td>
            </template>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </v-table>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<style scoped>
  main {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .v-table {
    flex: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 0;
  }

  .v-table__wrapper table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 0 !important;
  }

  table {
    border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }

  table th {
    border-top: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  }

  table th + th {
    border-left: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  }

  table td + td {
    border-left: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  }
</style>
```

The example above works fine but now I want to introduce stacked column headers. When I change the  content to

```
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Header for col 1 and 2</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
```

( [updated playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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) )

you will see that only the "last" table header row is fixed. All rows above are lost when scrolling down.

My table is based on a configuration, headers and data are completely dynamic, the headers might look like this

[image]

Do you have any ideas how to fix all of them?

---

**Update** I can reproduce the problem with an official example

( [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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) )

( issue can be found here https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/17806 )

```
<template>
  <v-table fixed-header height="500">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Header of col 1 and 2</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Col 1</th>
        <th>Col 2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(item, index) in data" :key="index">
        <td>{{ index }} in col 1</td>
        <td>{{ index }} in col 2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </v-table>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
  import { ref } from "vue";

  const data = ref(Array(100).fill(null));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the resource `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.2.3/dist/vuetify-labs.css` there's a rule that is targeting only the last table row (`tr`) in the `thead`.

```
.v-table--fixed-header > .v-table__wrapper > table > thead > tr > th {
  border-bottom: 0px !important;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

If you could replicate that rule and assign it to the `thead` tag that could fix your problem.

```
thead {
  border-bottom: 0px !important;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

In other words, you need to make the whole `thead` sticky, not just the `th`

Comment: yeah I think there already is a PR for this https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/17806